# Google Maps from Firefox addon (without SDK)

Tags: google-maps-api-3, firefox-addon

I need to add a map in my adddon and I know how to do what I need in a "common webpage", like I did here: http://jsfiddle.net/hCymP/6/

The problem is I really don't know how to to the same in a Firefox Addon. I tryed importing the scripts with [LoadSubScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/mozIJSSubScriptLoader#loadSubScript%28%29) and also tryed adding a chrome html with the next line:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
```

But nothing works. The best solution I found was to add part of the code in [this file](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false) (the code of the script src) in my function, to import [this file](https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/13/11/main.js) with [loadSubScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/mozIJSSubScriptLoader#loadSubScript%28%29), and all my function is executed but an empty div is returned.

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");

window.google = {};
window.google.maps = {};
window.google.maps.modules = {};
var modules = window.google.maps.modules;
var loadScriptTime = (new window.Date).getTime();

window.google.maps.__gjsload__ = function(name, text) { modules[name] = text;};
window.google.maps.Load = function(apiLoad) {
    delete window.google.maps.Load;
    apiLoad([0.009999999776482582,[[["https://mts0.googleapis.com/vt?lyrs=m@227000000\u0026src=api\u0026hl=en-US\u0026","https://mts1.googleapis.com/vt?lyrs=m@227000000\u0026src=api\u0026hl=en-US\u0026"],null,null,null,null,"m@227000000"],[["https://khms0.googleapis.com/kh?v=134\u0026hl=en-US\u0026","https://khms1.googleapis.com/kh?v=134\u0026hl=en-US\u0026"],null,null,null,1,"134"],[["https://mts0.googleapis.com/vt?lyrs=h@227000000\u0026src=api\u0026hl=en-US\u0026","https://mts1.googleapis.com/vt?lyrs=h@227000000\u0026src=api\u0026hl=en-US\u0026"],null,null,null,null,"h@227000000"],[["https://mts0.googleapis.com/vt?lyrs=t@131,r@227000000\u0026src=api\u0026hl=en-US\u0026","https://mts1.googleapis.com/vt?lyrs=t@131,r@227000000\u0026src=api\u0026hl=en-US\u0026"],null,null,null,null,"t@131,r@227000000"],null,null,[["https://cbks0.googleapis.com/cbk?","https://cbks1.googleapis.com/cbk?"]],[["https://khms0.googleapis.com/kh?v=80\u0026hl=en-US\u0026","https://khms1.googleapis.com/kh?v=80\u0026hl=en-US\u0026"],null,null,null,null,"80"],[["https://mts0.googleapis.com/mapslt?hl=en-US\u0026","https://mts1.googleapis.com/mapslt?hl=en-US\u0026"]],[["https://mts0.googleapis.com/mapslt/ft?hl=en-US\u0026","https://mts1.googleapis.com/mapslt/ft?hl=en-US\u0026"]],[["https://mts0.googleapis.com/vt?hl=en-US\u0026","https://mts1.googleapis.com/vt?hl=en-US\u0026"]],[["https://mts0.googleapis.com/mapslt/loom?hl=en-US\u0026","https://mts1.googleapis.com/mapslt/loom?hl=en-US\u0026"]],[["https://mts0.googleapis.com/mapslt?hl=en-US\u0026","https://mts1.googleapis.com/mapslt?hl=en-US\u0026"]],[["https://mts0.googleapis.com/mapslt/ft?hl=en-US\u0026","https://mts1.googleapis.com/mapslt/ft?hl=en-US\u0026"]]],["en-US","US",null,0,null,null,"https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/","https://csi.gstatic.com","https://maps.googleapis.com","https://maps.googleapis.com"],["https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/13/11","3.13.11"],[3047554353],1.0,null,null,null,null,1,"",null,null,1,"https://khms.googleapis.com/mz?v=134\u0026",null,"https://earthbuilder.googleapis.com","https://earthbuilder.googleapis.com",null,"https://mts.googleapis.com/vt/icon"], loadScriptTime);
};


//I can't use document.write but use loadSubScript insthead
Services.scriptloader.loadSubScript("chrome://googleMaps/content/Google-Maps-V3.js", window, "utf8"); //chrome://MoWA/content/Google-Maps-V3.js", window, "utf8");

var mapContainer = window.content.document.createElement('canvas');
    mapContainer.setAttribute('id', "map");
    mapContainer.setAttribute('style',"width: 500px; height: 300px");
    mapContainer.style.backgroundColor = "red";

var mapOptions = {
    center: new window.google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
    zoom: 5,
    mapTypeId: window.google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}

var map = new window.google.maps.Map(mapContainer,mapOptions);
return mapContainer;
```

Can you help me? I'm developing a "Firefox for Android" addon and that's why I need to do things like *window.content.*document.createElement because document is not declared, only window and I think thats may be the problem... But I can't declare everything if I don't know what Google Maps uses.

Added: I also read that Google Maps API Team has specific code that disallows you from copying the main script locally. In particular, that code "expires" every so many hours. I'm  combined part of this script: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false   because I can't execute this directly (Error: write called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLDocument). So I don't have any alternative!

Comment: You are using a canvas-element, not a div, but  canvas is not designed for containing HTML-content(usually a browser will only show HTML-content in a canvas when the browser did not support the canvas-element)

Comment: @Dr.Molle I also tryed with div element and didn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

Use an `iframe` (type=content if in XUL) to display web content. There you can include whatever scripts you like. The content in the `iframe` will not have any special privileges, or at least should not. If you need to communicate with the privileged add-on part of your code, you can use e.g. regular HTML events (`createEvent`, `addEventListener` and friends) or the  `postMessage` web API to pass messages.

Do not try to load remote code directly into other pages, or worse, into the browser, as this is a compatibility and security nightmare.
Because loading remote code and/or code not properly reviewed for running in a privileged context, the platform will refuse to load such scripts from remote sources (http, etc.) via loadSubScript, etc.

Should be noted, that if you'd later like to host your add-on on addons.mozilla.org and still do include remote scripts in privileged code, your add-on will be rejected until you fix it.
Also, mozilla might blocklist your add-on even if you host elsewhere if it is discovered that there are known security vulnerabilities in your add-on, per the [Add-on Guidelines](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/Add-on_guidelines).